# Get the date in HTTP format using _time or _dateTimeConvert function in JMeter

Tags: date, jmeter

I have the JMeter test where I use the function `${_time()}` to get the current time in epoch format.

I know how to convert this date in simple format e.g. `${__dateTimeConvert(${__time},,M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a)}`, but I'm not be able to convert the date in HTTP formats as: "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", "EEE, dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss zzz", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz" , e.g. Wed, 21 Oct 2020 07:28:00 GMT.

Is it possible for listed functions or I have to use JSR223 sampler with a custom script?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `time` function with format as

```
 ${__time(EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy,)}
```

Use [__timeShift](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) with only relevant format parameter:

```
${__timeShift(EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy)}
```

> timeShift function returns a date in the given format with the specified amount of seconds, minutes, hours, days or months added

Comment: Hi, It's almost worked for me. I need to get the date in this format Wed, 21 Oct 2020 07:28:00 GMT. and then compare with the result from the response body, but I faced several problems: _timeshift function is not working with this format, also I get the date in local time and my local time zone instead of GMT. So, do you have an idea of how I can set up the current time and then read as a variable in format Wed, 21 Oct 2020 07:28:00 GMT ?

Comment: You can show timezone with `z` and add hours using third parameter `P{number of hours }D for example add 5 hours: `${__timeShift(MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z,,P5H,,)}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use following letters in the format string for generating custom formats

[image]

**Few Examples**

[image]

The format to be passed to [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).Java API [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) could be useful for generating custom formats.